# Is this text on a help article a bug (or something else)?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

In the [editing help article](https://superuser.com/editing-help) it says:

> if(thisSite.Settings.Site.StyleCodeByDefault) { Code blocks will be
> highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the syntax highlighting
> language will be inferred from the question's tags. } else { Code
> blocks can be highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the
> syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's
> tags. }

Why is this?

Comment: We're working on some back end JavaScript stuff and that may have caused this - in the interim it seems to have been fixed, so I'm marking this status-compelted.

Comment: @Catija Confirming it is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possibly a bug, and that the site parser is supposed to evaluate `thisSite.Settings.Site.StyleCodeByDefault` to write either

> Code blocks **will be** highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's tags.

or

> Code blocks **can be** highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's tags.

(emphasis mine)

The same is present at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help so it seems this is a platform wide bug. I've retagged your question to get someone from Stack Exchange to review.

Comment: I thought this was some behind the scenes java stuff!! or some kind of joke-y thing.

Comment: I also thought to post at Meta.SE but was afraid of getting beaten to death of down votes.

Comment: That would be a good place to go, I don't see why a genuine bug report would get downvotes unless it has already been reported.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I do admit at first glance it does look like a "codeblock" joke, but the statement itself looks a lot more intentional than just a joke. It's an explicit wording change between "will" and "can" and feels more like a page compilation directive that is not properly handled.

Comment: I know, I mentioned the joke possibility as a option I had in my mind...

Comment: I don't know, sometimes they just ignore bugs so, It is good to first write a support-tagged post and play the fool.